# Return list from a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to LISP and was wondering how to return a list from a function.
I need to write a function that takes a list as an input and outputs a list.

If first and last elements are even numbers:
return a list with first ** 2 and last ** 4
else
return a list with first and last elements

How do I return a list correctly?

```
(defun test (elements)
    (if (and (numberp (nth 0 elements))
            (numberp (last elements)))
        (if (and (evenp (nth 0 elements))
            (evenp (last elements)))
            (return from test (list (expt (last elements) 2) (expt (nth 0 elements) 4)))
        )
    )
    (return from test (list (nth 0 elements) (last elements)))
)
```

Comment: Lisp just returns the value computed from the expression, possibly returning upwards through multiple calls. Generally there is no RETURN statement necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
(cond ((foo-p n) (list 1 2))  ; returns the list
      ((bar-p m) (list 3 4))  ; returns the list
      (t         (list 5 6))) ; returns the list
```

or

```
(if (foo-p n)
    (list 1 2)                ; returns the list
    (if (bar-p m)
        (list 3 4)            ; returns the list
        (list 5 6)))          ; returns the list
```

Answer (score 2):

A list is a chain of pairs. eg. `(1 2 3)` is created with `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`. If you know this in your heart it will be much easier to do list processing.

Because of the structure fo a list a list is created from end to beginning and iterated from beginning to end.

Eg. replacing first element is easy. You `(cons (do-something (car elements)) (cdr elements))` and you have a list with the first element changed. You could do the same with `(reverse elements)` to alter the last element before reversing it again. Put these two together and you have a solution.

No `return` is necessary. eg. if the body if a function is as follows the argument will get a new element in the beginning if `some-expr` is truthy and the argument if it is not.

```
(if some-expr
    (cons 3 elements)
    elements)
```

Every part of lisp works like this. An expression can be seen as computing a returned value. eg. `some-expr` returns a value that is evaluated by `if`. Eg. it's not the function scope you are exiting, but each level of an expression as well.